# Move files with certain suffix to a directory

Tags: shell-script, ksh

Hi I have the below lines in my .ksh script:

```
for file in $fileDirectory/*.$yesterdayDate
do
mv *.$yesterdayDate "$fileDirectory/$yesterdayDate"
done
```

However, when I execute this I get the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘*.20200607’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘*.20200607’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘*.20200607’: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You talk about `ksh` but have tagged the question with `bash`...

Comment: Sorry must have mis-clicked, now it is fixed. Thanks @HaukeLaging

Comment: You are looping using the variable `file`, but never use it in the loop. Assuming there were 10 such files originally, this would execute the "move all files with that suffix to the target dir" 10 times, which after the first time must fail as the files are then already moved ...

Comment: You first have to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are no files matching `*.20200607` in the current directory. This is probably not surprising at all.

You build a loop around the variable `file` without ever using it.

```
for file in "$fileDirectory"/*."$yesterdayDate"; do
    mv "$file" "$fileDirectory/$yesterdayDate"
done
```

But why not just

```
mv "$fileDirectory"/*."$yesterdayDate" "$fileDirectory/$yesterdayDate"
```

? Too many files for the `mv` call? Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
mv $file "$fileDirectory/$yesterdayDate"
```

inside for loop

OR

you can do it using `find` command:

```
find $fileDirectory -name \*.$yesterdayDate -type f -exec mv {} $fileDirectory/$yesterdayDate \;
```